# Does $X\overset{f}{\rightarrow} Y\rightarrow0$ being exact imply $\operatorname{coker}f=0$?

Tags: category-theory

In a category with zero object, it is easy to see that if $0\rightarrow X\overset{f}{\rightarrow} Y$ is exact then $\ker f=0$, since $0\rightarrow X$ is monic and hence is its own image. However, when I try to prove its dual statement,  that if $X\overset{f}{\rightarrow}Y\rightarrow0$ is exact then $\operatorname{coker} f=0$, somehow I can't. Am I overlooking certain fact, or is it true at all? Or is it a corroboration of my mounting suspicion that things are not exactly symmetrical between a category and its dual category?

Comment: You've already proved the cokernel thing too! It _does_ follow by duality from the statement you proved for the kernel. It might help to dualize your proof step by step to see what's going on.

Comment: The exactness of $X\overset{f}{\rightarrow} Y\rightarrow0$ implies that $\operatorname{id}_Y:Y\rightarrow Y$ is the image of $f$, so provided that the category has epimorphic images, then it follows that $f$ is an epimorphism. But I can't seem to go anywhere without the assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\inv}{^{-1}}
\newcommand{\hei}{\operatorname{ht}}
\newcommand{\pr}{\mathfrak{p}}
\newcommand{\spr}{_\mathfrak{p}}
\newcommand{\mb}[1]{\mbox{#1}}
\newcommand{\supp}{\operatorname{Supp}}
\newcommand{\sst}{\subset}
\newcommand{\spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}
\newcommand{\ann}{\operatorname{ann}}
\newcommand{\st}{such that }
\newcommand{\esq}{exact sequence}
\newcommand{\cx}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\iso}{isomorphism}
\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}
\newcommand{\be}{\beta}
\newcommand{\fall}{\ \ \forall}
\newcommand{\hmm}{homomorphism}
\newcommand{\dra}{\dashrightarrow}
\newcommand{\mt}{\mapsto}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand{\cc}{\circ}
\newcommand{\id}{\operatorname{id}}
\newcommand{\itk}[1]{{\it #1}}
\newcommand{\ras}{\overset{\sim}{\ra}}
\newcommand{\amod}{$A$-module}
\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}
\newcommand{\ten}{\otimes}
\newcommand{\opl}{\oplus}
\newcommand{\bs}{\bigskip}
\newcommand{\bil}{\operatorname{Bil}}
\newcommand{\bea}[1]{\begin{eqnarray*}#1\end{eqnarray*}}
\newcommand{\rf}[1]{\overset{#1}{\rightarrow}}
\newcommand{\rff}[1]{\overset{#1}{\longrightarrow}}
\newcommand{\ifof}{if and only if }
\newcommand{\D}{\mathcal{D}}
\newcommand{\la}{\leftarrow}
\newcommand{\Ra}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\La}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\B}{\mathcal{B}}
\newcommand{\du}{^*}
\newcommand{\ddu}{^{**}}
\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}
\newcommand{\setst}[2]{\left\{ #1 \ | \ #2 \right\}}
\newcommand{\pp}{^\perp}
\newcommand{\lf}[1]{\overset{#1}{\leftarrow}}
\newcommand{\lff}[1]{\overset{#1}{\longleftarrow}}
\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}
\newcommand{\sur}{\twoheadrightarrow}
\newcommand{\krn}{\operatorname{ker}}
\newcommand{\hra}{\hookrightarrow}
\newcommand{\mtt}[1]{\ar@{|->}[#1]}
\newcommand{\hyp}{\mathbb{H}}
\newcommand{\xym}[1]{$$\xymatrix{#1}$$}
\newcommand{\las}{\overset{\sim}{\la}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\dm}{\operatorname{dim}}
\newcommand{\qr}{\mathfrak{q}}
\newcommand{\si}{S^{-1}}
\newcommand{\sqr}{_{\mathfrak{q}}}
\newcommand{\bb}{\backslash}
\newcommand{\noe}{Noetherian}
\newcommand{\rr}{\mathfrak{r}}
\newcommand{\ass}{\operatorname{Ass}}
\newcommand{\ben}[1]{\begin{enumerate}#1\end{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\smaxi}{_{\mathfrak{m}}}
\newcommand{\maxi}{\mathfrak{m}}
\newcommand{\kp}{\kappa(\pr)}
\newcommand{\tid}{\tb{id}}
\newcommand{\pres}{\mathcal{P}_\bullet}
\newcommand{\pl}{\partial}
\newcommand{\cok}{\operatorname{cok}}
\newcommand{\os}[2]{\overset{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\us}[2]{\underset{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\tor}{\operatorname{Tor}}
\newcommand{\nz}{\bb\set{0}}
\newcommand{\G}{\mathcal{G}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathcal{C}}
\newcommand{\E}{\mathcal{E}}
\newcommand{\V}{\mathcal{V}}
\newcommand{\dep}{\operatorname{depth}}
\newcommand{\nn}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\naxi}{\mathfrak{n}}
\newcommand{\sstt}{\varsubsetneqq}
\newcommand{\grd}{\operatorname{grade}}
\newcommand{\ext}{\operatorname{Ext}}
\newcommand{\pd}{\operatorname{pd}}
\newcommand{\Grd}{\operatorname{Grade}}
\newcommand{\Dep}{\operatorname{Depth}}
\newcommand{\asq}{a_1,\ldots,a_d}
\newcommand{\an}{a_1,\ldots,a_n}
\newcommand{\K}{\mathcal{K}}
\newcommand{\bu}{_{\bullet}}
\newcommand{\ep}{\epsilon}
\newcommand{\tena}{\ten_A}
\newcommand{\loc}{$(A,\maxi)$}
\newcommand{\lab}{Let $A$ be a \noe\ ring. }
\newcommand{\ets}{\emptyset}
\newcommand{\amods}{$A$-modules}
\newcommand{\mspec}{\operatorname{mSpec}}
\newcommand{\lra}{$\Leftrightarrow$}
\newcommand{\tra}{$\Rightarrow$}
\newcommand{\tla}{$\Leftarrow$}
\newcommand{\sm}{\smallskip}
\newcommand{\beq}[1]{\begin{equation}#1\end{equation}}
\newcommand{\tesq}{there is an exact sequence}
\newcommand{\td}{\operatorname{td}}
\newcommand{\ffall}{\qquad\forall}
\newcommand{\del}{\delta}
\newcommand{\isos}{isomorphisms}
\newcommand{\Qq}{\mathcal{Q}}
\newcommand{\Tcd}{There is a commutative diagram}
\newcommand{\cd}{commutative diagram}
\newcommand{\ad}{\operatorname{ad}}
\newcommand{\rot}[1]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$#1$}}
\newcommand{\fga}{f.g.~\amod}
\newcommand{\Hh}{\mathcal{H}}
\newcommand{\tcd}{there is a \cd}
\newcommand{\tis}{there is an \iso}
\newcommand{\Tis}{There is an \iso}
\newcommand{\gam}{\gamma}
\newcommand{\hmms}{homomorphisms}
\newcommand{\Del}{\Delta}
\newcommand{\fgas}{f.g.~\amods}
\newcommand{\lam}{\lambda}
\newcommand{\ab}{\bar{A}}
\newcommand{\Tesq}{There is an exact sequence}
\newcommand{\inc}{\operatorname{inc.}}
\newcommand{\isoc}{isomorphic}
\newcommand{\Ll}{\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\piac}{^p_i(A;\C)}
\newcommand{\kpi}{^p_i}
\newcommand{\veq}{\ar@{}[d]|{\rot{=}}}
\newcommand{\res}{A/\maxi}
\newcommand{\bopl}{\bigoplus}
\newcommand{\Pp}{\mathcal{P}}
\newcommand{\qres}{\Qq^{\bullet}}
\newcommand{\wdf}{well-defined}
\newcommand{\tiss}{there are \isos}
\newcommand{\wrt}{with respect to}
\newcommand{\gl}{\operatorname{gl}}
\newcommand{\esqs}{exact sequences}
\newcommand{\qqq}{\qquad\quad}
\newcommand{\db}[1]{\bar{\bar{#1}}}
\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}
\newcommand{\sesq}{short \esq}
\newcommand{\vsp}{vector space}
\newcommand{\ppp}{^{\perp\perp}}
\newcommand{\Ee}{\mathcal{E}}
\newcommand{\Oo}{\mathcal{O}}
\newcommand{\snaxi}{_{\naxi}}
\newcommand{\Ss}{\mathcal{S}}
\newcommand{\fs}{\mathscr{F}}
\newcommand{\gs}{\mathscr{G}}
\newcommand{\oo}{\mathscr{O}}
\newcommand{\fsp}{\fs^+}
\newcommand{\T}{\mathcal{T}}
\newcommand{\psu}{^+}
\newcommand{\hs}{\mathscr{H}}
\newcommand{\shf}{sheaf}
\newcommand{\svs}{sheaves}
\newcommand{\as}{\mathscr{A}}
\newcommand{\U}{\mathcal{U}}
\newcommand{\ds}{_*}
\newcommand{\dlim}{\varinjlim}
\newcommand{\tsp}{topological space}
\newcommand{\bsu}{|_U}
\newcommand{\bsv}{|_V}
\newcommand{\sal}{_\al}
\newcommand{\sbe}{_\be}
\newcommand{\net}{non-empty}
\newcommand{\irred}{irreducible}
\newcommand{\xox}{(X,\fs)}
\newcommand{\yoy}{(Y,\oo_Y)}
\newcommand{\dla}{\dashleftarrow}
\newcommand{\proj}{\operatorname{Proj}}
\newcommand{\hmg}{homogeneous}
\newcommand{\vb}{\bar{V}}
\newcommand{\con}{^c}
\newcommand{\nbh}{neighborhood}
\newcommand{\shp}{^\#}
\newcommand{\oab}{of abelian groups}
\newcommand{\A}{\mathcal{A}}
\newcommand{\MM}{\mathscr{M}}
\newcommand{\NN}{\mathscr{N}}
\newcommand{\ilim}{\varprojlim}
\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathscr{Z}}
\newcommand{\tm}{\tilde{M}}
\newcommand{\tn}{\tilde{N}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathcal{N}}
\newcommand{\sab}{_{\al\be}}
\newcommand{\nbhs}{neighborhoods}
\newcommand{\quot}{\operatorname{quot.}}
\newcommand{\sx}{_x}
\newcommand{\Ww}{\mathcal{W}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathcal{R}}
\newcommand{\Ca}{\mathbf{A}}
\newcommand{\Cr}{\mathbf{R}}
\newcommand{\Cc}{\mathbf{C}}
\newcommand{\Co}{\mathbf{O}}
\newcommand{\Ct}{\mathbf{T}}
\newcommand{\Cm}{\mathbf{M}}
\newcommand{\Calg}{\mathbf{Alg}}
\newcommand{\Cab}{\mathbf{Ab}}
\newcommand{\elt}{element}
\newcommand{\elts}{elements}
\newcommand{\csr}{\operatorname{Cl}}
\newcommand{\tsps}{topological spaces}
\newcommand{\CC}{\mathscr{C}}
\newcommand{\DD}{\mathscr{D}}
\newcommand{\opla}{\opl\sal}
\newcommand{\leri}{\leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\ang}[1]{\langle #1\rangle}
\newcommand{\hpsi}{\hat{\psi}}
\newcommand{\hphi}{\hat{\phi}}
\newcommand{\resp}{respectively}
\newcommand{\abg}{abelian group}
\newcommand{\abgs}{abelian groups}
\newcommand{\opn}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
\newcommand{\mono}{monomorphism}
\newcommand{\epi}{epimorphism}
\newcommand{\cds}{commutative diagrams}
\newcommand{\qq}{\qquad}
\newcommand{\mf}{\mapsfrom}
\newcommand{\aalg}{$A$-algebra}
\newcommand{\aalgs}{$A$-algebras}
\newcommand{\Ch}{\mathbf{H}}
\newcommand{\sgam}{_\gam}
\newcommand{\sdel}{_\del}
\newcommand{\Cring}{\mathbf{Ring}}
\newcommand{\Cmod}{\mathbf{Mod}}
\newcommand{\Cset}{\mathbf{Set}}
\newcommand{\sag}{_{\al\gam}}
\newcommand{\sbg}{_{\be\gam}}
\newcommand{\Cb}{\mathbf{B}}
\newcommand{\tphi}{\tilde{\phi}}
\newcommand{\ms}{\mathscr{M}}
\newcommand{\rs}{\mathscr{R}}
\newcommand{\ssc}{\mathscr{S}}
\newcommand{\ns}{\mathscr{N}}
\newcommand{\eq}{\operatorname{eq}}
\newcommand{\aff}{\mathbb{A}}
\newcommand{\prj}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\htau}{\hat{\tau}}
\newcommand{\hsigma}{\hat{\sigma}}
\newcommand{\alg}{algebra}
\newcommand{\algs}{algebras}
\newcommand{\tpsi}{\tilde{\psi}}
\newcommand{\monos}{monomorphisms}
\newcommand{\epis}{epimorphisms}
\newcommand{\ks}{\mathscr{K}}
\newcommand{\TT}{\mathscr{T}}
\newcommand{\tenz}{\ten_\Z}
\newcommand{\sk}{\mathscr{K}}
\newcommand{\II}{\mathscr{I}}
\newcommand{\rat}{\rightarrowtail}
\newcommand{\saL}{_{\al\in\Lambda}}
\newcommand{\timd}{\times\cdots\times}
\newcommand{\tenad}{\tena\cdots\tena}
\newcommand{\tend}{\ten\cdots\ten}
\newcommand{\slam}{_\lam}
\newcommand{\ulam}{^\lam}
\newcommand{\uls}{\ulam\sal}
\newcommand{\omd}{$\oo$-module}
\newcommand{\omds}{$\oo$-modules}
\newcommand{\shn}{sheafification}
\newcommand{\shns}{sheafifications}
\newcommand{\Cpsh}{\mathbf{Psh}}
\newcommand{\Csh}{\mathbf{Sh}}
\newcommand{\su}{_u}
$

**Proposition**    $\ $  Let
$$X\rf{\phi}Y\ra0$$
be an exact sequence in a category with kernels. Then $\cok\phi=0$.

**Proof** We will show that $Y\ra0$ is a cokernel of $\phi$. This is equivalent to showing that if $\psi:Y\ra Z$ is a morphism such that $\psi\cc\phi=0$, then $\psi=0$. So let $\psi:Y\ra Z$ be such a morphism, and $j:\krn\psi\ra Y$ its kernel.
Since $\psi\cc\phi=0$, there exists a morphism $\hphi:X\dra\krn\psi$ such that $j\cc\hphi=\phi$.
$$\xymatrix{& \krn\psi \ar@{>->}[d]^j \\
\ar@{-->}[ru]^{\hphi} X \ar[r]^\phi & Y \ar[r] \ar[d]_\psi & 0 \ar@{-->}[ld] \\
& Z}$$
By exactness, $\id_Y:Y\ra Y$ is an image of $\phi$. Hence, there exists a morphism $\al:Y\dra\krn\psi$ such that $j\cc\al=\id_Y$. Then $\psi=\psi\cc j\cc\al=0$.